# How can I specify repository path using chef client local mode

Tags: repository, chef-infra

I understand it will scan current directory for repository. is there an alternative except switch current working directory to where local repository is before invoking chef client local mode

Comment: You want to have chef repo lookup afte your local repostiry lookup ? couldnt get your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what you used to do with chef-solo (in the `solo.rb`) file, you can do with your `client.rb` file:

```
cookbook_path   ["/path/to/directory/containing/cookbooks"]
```

From the [Chef docs](https://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_client.html) - `cookbook_path` "The sub-directory for cookbooks on the chef-client. This value can be a string or an array of file system locations, processed in the specified order. The last cookbook is considered to override local modifications."

Otherwise it will scan the current directory repo.